# Hey subform - let go of my Table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm having a bit of an issue with timing, I think, that's driving me batty!

1. I have a Form with a subform with a Table as recordsource (as a datasheet)
2. Users can edit the data in the datasheet
3. Upon closing the form (via btnSave), I intend to run a function that exports the datasheet, with its changes to an XLS via Transfer spreadsheet.
4. Access is complaining the table is "already in use"
5. I have attempted to set the subform's recordsource = "" then requery
6. Same complaint from Access about the table - but table is not open!

Any suggestions how and where to attach the export function?

Note:  The export function works just fine under its own dedicated button on the MainForm.  I just want to run this same function when I close the form/subform.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here but I wonder have you tried setting the subform control's `Source Object` property to `""`?

Comment: HansUp, No luck - err 2465.  Synax as follows?  Forms![Matched]![Matched subform].Form.SourceObject = ""

Comment: A subform *control* contains a form, specified by its (the control's)  `Source Object` property.  You would need something like `NameOfSubformCONTROL.SourceObject = vbNullString`  In other words, there should not be any `.Form.` in there at all because a form does not have a `Source Object` property --- it has a `Record Source`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HansUp, I can confirm the following syntax also works:

```
Forms![Matched]![Matched subform].SourceObject = ""
```

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Crude, but effective:

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Forms![Matched]![Matched subform]", acSaveNo
```

No more complaints about the locked table

HansUp, I'll play with that syntax; always fuzzy trial and error on those pesky sufbform properties.